# Why does the use of [ versus [[ sometimes produce the SAME result (rather than different results)?

Tags: r

The R documentation (as well as extensive R folklore) [describes the different operators for extraction](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Extract).

However, it appears that neither the documentation nor the folklore explain why it is that the use of *different* operators ( `[` versus `[[` ) can return *identical* results. Can someone provide an explanation? Note that I'm asking not why they can produce different results, but why they can sometimes produce an identical result. Why does `x[2]` (see below) evaluate identically to `x[[2]]`?

```r
x <- c("a","b","c") ; x[2] ; x[[2]]
## [1] "b"
## [1] "b"
```

Comment: It will have an effect on a `list` or `data.frame`.  Also, check the difference with `x[1:2]` and `x[[1:2]]`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked questions are focussed on the _differences_ between the two syntaxes, not why they're sometimes identical. Which is not (obviously) explicitly stated in the docs either.

Comment: The real answer (as far as I know) is that there is no distinction in R between a value (e.g. `3`) and a vector of length 1 (e.g. `c(3)`). `x[[2]]` should give you a value and `x[2]` should give you a vector of length 1. But these two things are identical.

Comment: @MattB, please post your comments as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no distinction in R between a value (e.g. `3`) and a vector of length 1 (e.g. `c(3)`). `x[[2]]` should give you a value and `x[2]` should give you a vector of length 1. But these two things are identical.

Comment: There is a difference: `x[2]` preserves the name if there is one, while this name is dropped with `x[[2]]`. Try `x <- c(a = 1, b = 2)`.